# When a larger number of queries will show the error 503

Tags: javascript

i use this javascript code

```
(function($){

function handleResponse(response){
    $('#content').append('<div>' + response['msg'] + '</div>');
}

var timestamp = 0;
var url = './chat_backend.php';
var noerror = true;
var ajax;

function connect() {
    ajax = $.ajax(url, {
        type: 'get',
        data: { 'timestamp' : timestamp },
        success: function(transport) {
            eval('var response = '+transport);
            timestamp = response['timestamp'];
            handleResponse(response);
            noerror = true;
        },
        complete: function(transport) {
            (!noerror) && setTimeout(function(){ connect() }, 5000) || connect();
            noerror = false;
        }
    });
}

function doRequest(request) {
    $.ajax(url, {
        type: 'get',
        data: { 'msg' : request, 'id_uzivatele' : '1'}
    });
}

$('#cometForm').live('submit', function(){
    doRequest($('#zprava').val());
    $('#zprava').val('');
    return false;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    connect();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Problem is, that sometimes when a larger number of queries will show the error 503.

any idea why?

I would like the code that make such a small chat, but this bug me that currently hinder. :-/

Thanks, Patrik

Comment: What do you mean "larger number queries"?

Comment: ["The server is currently unavailable (**because it is overloaded** or down for maintenance)."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_error) Pretty obvious, isn't it?

Comment: kodmanyagha: When multiple users are connected, so it jumps up and throws timeout error 503

Comment: str: Yes, but I do not know how to overwrite that it run okay

Comment: That is not a frontend problem, but a backend problem. Have a look at your server logs for details.

Comment: Log is: 

 ERROR 1: mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 310 seconds

 ERROR 2: End of script output before headers: chat_backend.php
 ERROR 3: mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /data/web/virtuals/159909/php-wrapper-70